# requests.get() behaving erratically?

Tags: python, xml, rss

I've been coding XML parser using python where I was taking RSS feeds of news websites as input. I implemented a loadRSS() function where I used requests.get() on the url of the particular feed. My code

```
def loadRSS(src,filename):

resp = requests.get(src)

#print resp.content
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

Now I have various sub-directories according to different sections of news each having their separate RSS feed url, so there are folders like sports, science etc. each having a source.txt file in which there is the corresponding url of the RSS feed. I am using os.walk() to traverse  through each file

```
    for root, sub, f in os.walk(rootdirectory):
    for f1 in f:
        if f1=='source.txt':
            src=""
            with open(os.path.join(root,f1),'r') as f2:
                src=f2.readline()

            loadRSS(src,os.path.join(root,"topnewsfeed.xml"))
            newsitems = parseXML(os.path.join(root,"topnewsfeed.xml"))
            savetoCSV(newsitems,os.path.join(root,"topnews.csv"))
```

When I am running my script I got an error

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 22, column 311
```

so I decided to check the xml files which were being formed by the loadRSS() function. To my surprise, different kind of data was being fetched for different RSS feeds (even though I was using the same logic for putting the data on xml file ). For example, for the RSS feed corresponding to topnews/rssfeed.xml of 'Hindustan Times' (sorry can't post all the links as I don't have enough reputation),the xml file was formed perfectly according to the page source. But for another RSS link http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/1081479906.cms I got  an erratic [xml file on my system](https://pastebin.com/a3S1W1xS)

which was not in accordance with the xml of that RSS page. I've tried really hard to debug it but still have no clue as to what might be causing it and how it can be rectified, and it is a great cause of irritation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The erratic XML file is obviously a HTML file which is never supposed to be valid XML. Ask the maintainer of the site why you are receiving something different than the expected XML here...this is outside the scope of SO and the behaviour of the XML parser is correct.